# RestKit iOS application crashes on request

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, ios6, restkit

i have a big Problem with Objective C and RestKit.
On application startup i want to click a Button.
But if i click the button instantly after the startup my application crashes.
If i wait a few seconds everything works fine.

Anyone an idea?
That's my code

```
- (void)sendRequest {
// Perform a simple HTTP GET and call me back with the results
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/user" delegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
  if ([response isSuccessful]) {
    NSLog(@"HTTP status code:     %d", response.statusCode);
    NSLog(@"HTTP status message:  %@", [response localizedStatusCodeString]);
  }
}
```

The client will be created in de "AppDelegate" after startup

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://192.168.0.6:8080"];
[client setPassword:@"user"];
[client setUsername:@"user"];
[client setAuthenticationType:RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic];
client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;
```

The 'sendRequest' Methode will be called after i pressed the button.

Sorry, my english isn't very good.
I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: The debugger output is: (lldb)
It jumps to RKResponse.m - if ([[_request delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveResponse:)]) { - and says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xc0000008)

Answer (score 3):

I have exectly the same problem..
Able to fix this with blocks

```
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://your.api.com"];
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];

RKRequest *request = [client get:@"/method/name" queryParameters:nil delegate:nil];
request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [response bodyAsString]);
};
```